# Android ListView how to scroll vertically and horizontally ?

Tags: android, listview, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling, two-way

I want my Listview to scroll both vertically and Horizontally! I can able to scroll the listItem horizontally but I want my whole listview to move horizontally and vertically. Can anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `RecyclerView` and put it inside `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: It sounds like ListView is not the view of choice you want. I would consider using a ScrollView of some sort, as @BatuhanCoşkun said

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

Download and import ,For scrolling listview Horizontaly

https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView